Finiteness of morphism on some open neighborhood from finiteness of the induced morphism of fibers ( Gortz, Algebraic Geometry, Proposition 12.93 )
I am reading the Gortz, Wedhorn Algebraic Geometry, Proof of Proposition 12.93 and stuck at some step :

Proposition 12.93. : Let $S$ be a scheme, let $X$ and $Y$ be $S$-schemes such that the structure morphisms $g: X\to S$ and $h : Y \to S$ are proper, and let $f: X\to Y$ be an $S$-morphism. Let $s\in S$ be a point and let $f_s := f \times \operatorname{id}_{\kappa(s)} : g^{-1}(s)=X\otimes_S\kappa(s) \to h^{-1}(s)=Y\otimes_S\kappa(s)$ be the induced morphism of fibers. If $f_s$ is finite ( resp. a closed immersion ), then there exists an open neighborhood $U$ of $s$ such that $f|_{g^{-}(U)} : g^{-1}(U) \to h^{-1}(U)$ is finite ( resp. a closed immersion ).

Proof. We first claim that it suffices to show that for all $y\in h^{-1}(s)$ there exists an open neighborhood $V_y$ of $y$ such that the restriction $f^{-1}(V_y) \to V_y$ of $f$ is finite ( resp. a closed immersion ). Indeed, if $V$ denotes the union of open sets $V_y$, then the restriction $f^{-1}(V) \to V$ is finite ( resp. a closed immersion ) because both properties are local on the target. As $h$ is closed, there exists an open neighborhood $U$ of $s$ such that $h^{-1}(U) \subseteq V$ ( Remark 12.57 ; We accept usage of this remark ). This proves the claim ( We can conlude this claim easily ). The morphism $f$ is proper by Proposition 12.58 (3). If $f_s$ is finite, then the existence of an open neighborhood $V_y$ of $y$ for all $y\in h^{-1}(s)$ such that  the restriction $f^{-1}(V_y) \to V_y$ of $f$ is finite follows form Corollary 12.90 :

Corollary 12.90.  Let $f: X\to Y$ be a proper morphism and let $V$ be the set of $y\in Y$ such that $f^{=1}(y)$ is a finite set. Then $V$ is open in $Y$ and the restriction $f^{-1}(V)\to V$ of $f$ is a finite morphism.

Why the bold statement in the proof is true? It seems work but I am struggling with it hours and I can't prove it rigorously at all. Since $f_s$ is finite, it is quasi-finite and proper so for each $y\in h^{-1}(s)$, $f_s^{-1}(y) \subseteq g^{-1}(s)$ is finite. Furthermore, since $f_s^{-1}(y)$ is $\kappa(y)$-scheme of finite type, its underlying topological space is discrete so that it is affine. We may use this fact?
Can anyone please help, or hint?

For each $y\in h^{-1}(s)$, $f^{-1}(y)=f_s^{-1}(y)$ is finite so by the corollary we are done. This equality on fibres is just a property of the base change, namely $X\times_Y k(y)$ being isomorphic to $(X\times_S k(s))\times_{Y\times_S k(s)}(k(y)\times_S k(s))$.

Confusion for the last term : $k(y)\times_S k(s)$. My first calculation is,
$$(X\times_S k(s))\times_{Y\times_S k(s)}(k(y)\times_S k(s)) = (( X \times_Y Y)\times_S k(s)) \times_{Y \times_S k(s)} ( k(y)\times_S k(s)) =  X \times_Y (Y\times_S k(s)) \times_{Y \times_S k(s)} ( k(y)\times_S k(s))= X \times_Y (k(y) \times_S k(s)) .$$  Correct? If so, Where did the discrepancy(?) occurs?

$k(y)$ is already a $k(s)$-module by the induced map on local rings so we may omit it. (as $y\mapsto s$)

Q.1. ) Can you explain the comment more friendly, with example ?  Q.2.) And for $y \in h^{-1}(s) = Y \times_S k(s) \subseteq Y$, why the residue field of $y$ is of the form $k(y) \times_S k(s)$?

Anyway, key point is, $f^{-1}(y) = f_s^{-1}(y)$ for all $y\in h^{-1}(s)$. I think that we can show this from $f \circ \iota = \psi \circ f_s$, where $\iota : g^{-1}(s) \hookrightarrow X$, $ \psi : h^{-1}(s) \hookrightarrow Y$ are the inclusions ( we identifying $g^{-1} (s) = X \times_S k(s)$ , $ h^{-1}(s) = Y \times_S k(s)$. Thank you for pointing out.

It will be good if you explain your comment more in detail.

I mean, it is just $k(y)$. $Y$ is a scheme over $S$, hence residue field of $y$ is same both in $Y$ or in $Y\times_S k(s)$. We should write using inclusions to be precise, as you did (to identify two $y$'s).

Soft question : Why the residue field of $y$ is same both in $Y$ and $Y \times_S k(s)$ ? Note that $Y\times_S k(s) \to Y$ is immersion by base change. But residue field of subscheme may not be same as the residue field of the ambient scheme?

I think it is basic fact.

And.. I have further question regarding the Proposition 12.93 : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/5012063/gortz-and-wedhorn-algebraic-geometry-proof-of-proposition-12-93-final-statem. If you have time, could you please take look?
