Gortz and Wedhorn, Algebraic Geometry, proof of Proposition 12.93 ( Final statement )
I am reading proof of the Gortz, Wedhorn, Algebraic Geometry, Proposition 12.93 :

Proposition 12.93. : Let $S$ be a scheme, let $X$ and $Y$ be $S$-schemes such that the structure morphisms $g: X\to S$ and $h : Y \to S$ are proper, and let $f: X\to Y$ be an $S$-morphism. Let $s\in S$ be a point and let $f_s := f \times \operatorname{id}_{\kappa(s)} : g^{-1}(s)=X\otimes_S\kappa(s) \to h^{-1}(s)=Y\otimes_S\kappa(s)$ be the induced morphism of fibers. If $f_s$ is finite ( resp. a closed immersion ), then there exists an open neighborhood $U$ of $s$ such that $f|_{g^{-}(U)} : g^{-1}(U) \to h^{-1}(U)$ is finite ( resp. a closed immersion ).


Why the final statement makes the game over ?  ; i.e., why such $V_y$ makes $f^{-1}(V_y) \to V_y$ as topological closed embedding, as required in the first paragraph of the proof ? How can we choose?   As in the proof, $u_y$ is surjective for all $y \in h^{-1}(s)$. I understood this statement as $h^{-1}(s) \subseteq Y - \operatorname{Supp} ( \operatorname{Coker} u )$, which is an open set. True? If we let $V_y$ be this open set, then $f^{-1}(V_y) \to V_y$ is topological closed embedding? Or is there a restriction that makes it possible?
